# Integration of marketing cloud and third party?

Tags: automation, salesforce-marketing-cloud

The requirement is get the message data on submission of business user and **integrate Marketing cloud to third party platform and send binded message data in json format to third party**.On the basis of user activity either the message that send to third party is open or not . we need to resend the another json to the third party.

I need some better solution to meet the requirement.

Comment: Do you have any thought regarding that?

Comment: In Marketing cloud , we have option like cloud page ,script activity in automation studio and custom activity in journey builder api.But unable to unable which option is better to meet the requirement